# Doubly-linked list insert method implementation - what node is being search for

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm reviewing data structures and using [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/819324527X). When inserting a node, the list has to be traversed. But in the implementation of insert operation of a doubly-linked list DS I don't understand how can `k` be equal to `position`:

```
while ((k < position - 1) && temp->next!=NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
    k++;
}


if (k!=position) {   <----------------- this will true all the time?!
    printf("Desired position does not exist\n");
}
```

What am I missing? Or is this a typo?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the full method implementation:

```
void DLLInsert(struct DLLNode **head, int data, int position) {
    int k = 1;
    struct DLLNode *temp, *newNode;
    newNode = (struct DLLNode *) malloc(sizeof( struct DLLNode ));
    if (!newNode) {
        printf("Memory Error");
        return;
    }
    newNode->data = data;
    if (position == 1) {
        newNode->next = *head;
        newNode->prev = NULL;

        if (*head) {
            (*head)->prev = newNode;
        }
        *head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    temp = *head;
    while ((k < position - 1) && temp->next!=NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        k++;
    }

    if (k!=position) {
        printf("Desired position does not exist\n");
    }

    newNode->next=temp->next;
    newNode->prev=temp;

    if (temp->next) {
        temp->newNode->prev=newNode;
    }

    temp->next=newNode;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't miss something - `k!=position` will always be true at this point in the code; the only chance that `k!=position` would be `true` is when `position==1`, but in this case the function returns before reaching the `if`.
The check should rather be `if(temp==NULL)`.

There are some other issues, which let me think that the author did not test (actually not even compile) the code:

```
temp->newNode->prev=newNode;  // will this compile? I don't think that there's a member named `newNode`.
```

The code will crash if `*head` points to `NULL`, but one passes a `position > 1`;

Comment: I'm also wondering what kind of node it's being look for in the `while` loop - the node with the index at which to insert the node, previous or next? i.e. for a list of objects `{1},{2},{3},{4}` and inserting into the position of `3`, will the `temp` variable contain `{2}` or `{3}` or `{4}`?